# Do you provide DEBUG logging level for private methods?

Tags: java, debugging, logging, methods, private

I add logging for Java classes.In particularly, *logger.debug* level (for development mode).

As far private method called within public ones, is there sense to provide logging within private methods?
Is it efficiently?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not necessarily a matter of efficiency or not. You have to ask yourself: "Does that private method do something worthy of logging?"

In order to avoid performance issues, you can always check the logger whether it will log debug messages or not, before actually logging those messages. In log4j, you'd write

```
if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
  logger.debug("complicated" + "innefficient" + "string concatenation");
}
```

I imagine, other loggers provide similar concepts

Comment: Using [slf4j](http://www.slf4j.org/) removes the need to do `if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {...}`, so boilerplate code is reduced.

Comment: exactly, i use logger.isDebugEnabled() for "heavy" objects

Comment: darioo, the check is done to avoid lengthy string concatenations and other operations **before** the `logger.debug(...)` method call. If the "private method" in question is called 1 million times, then it may be important to check for the debug level being enabled first, before actually doing the logging

Answer (score 1):

yeah, if you want to "debug" your private methods in maintance mode or development, why not?
in production you'll set your logging level either warn or error! that's upto you...

Comment: in development mode or while you're searching for bugs, you don't need to think about efficiency, while you're basicly "debugging" your code :) set your debug-level error/warn in production.

Answer (score 1):

Of course. Private methods usually hide implementation detail, and that's where most bugs lurk. Put your logging statements where you feel the need, and disable them in production.

Comment: actually, i use slf4j and logger.isDebugEnabled(). Is it overhead?

Comment: @sergionni: it's not overhead, but it's unnecessary, since when calling `logger.debug(...)`, slf4j will check behind the hood if debug is enabled.

Answer (score 1):

Logging might seem wasteful when you don't need it, but it is indispensable when you do. Always provide meaningful log messages in your classes and functions. The log levels are there for you to be able to filter out the noise, and increase verbosity when you need it. Good loggers provide capabilities to change log levels at runtime.

Still, if you are worried about performance for whatever reason, you can use some simple guards to reduce the overhead of logging, especially debug logging, which is rarely on. With log4j/slf4j for example, you can wrap log debug statements in:

```
if(logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
    logger.debug("something");
}
```

slf4j additionally has a printf-like syntax which only does string formatting if the log level is correct.

```
logger.debug("Object {} is not valid!", obj);
```

Like darioo commented, this second form removed the need to check the log level before the log statement.

Comment: `this second form removed the need to check`: this is only true when formatting known values, if one of them is not trivial to produce a check is still needed.